# What is the intention of the following in the `q` promise library?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

What is the intention of the following in the `q` promise library? It constructs a promise, but I can see no way to resolve it?

I typically see a deferred when working with `q`.

```
q().then(function foo() {});
```

Comment: According to this (https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/q.js#L491) it constructs a promise without the use of a deferred, but I am not sure of how to resolve it given the lack of a deferred. I realise deferreds are not used in ES2015 Promises.

Comment: `Q(X)` does the same thing as `Promise.resolve(X)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates fulfilled promise.

```
q('test').then(x => console.log(x)); //test
```